# StackOverflowException unhandled on SqlDataAdapter.Fill()

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

StackOverflowException was unhandled.  I need help on this.  I get the error on the line

```
adp.Fill(ds)
```

Also I'm not sure why, but I can't remove `throw`, it says not all codes returning a value.

```
    string connStr = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbCustConn"].ToString();
    string cmdStr = "Select * from MainDB";

    public DAL() // default parameter.  Use?
    {
    }

        public DataTable Load() // what is this for? (loads all the records from the database)
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr);
            //SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdStr, connStr);
            SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdStr, connStr);  // SqlDataAdapater?  Load all?
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            try
            {
                adp.Fill(ds);
                return ds.Tables[0];
            }
            catch
            {
                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                ds.Dispose();
                adp.Dispose();
                conn.Close();
                conn.Dispose();
            }
        }
```

---

```
        public DataTable Load() // what is this for? (loads all the records from the database)
        {
            SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdStr, connStr);  // SqlDataAdapater?  Load all?
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr))
            {
                adp.Fill(ds);
                return ds.Tables[0];
            }
        }
```

---

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            BindGrid();
        }
    }

    private void BindGrid()
    {
        MasterCust.DataSource = GridDataSource();
        MasterCust.DataBind();
        //DetailCust.DataSource = ds2;
        //DetailCust.DataBind();
    }

    private DataTable GridDataSource()
    {
        BAL p = new BAL();
        DataTable dTable = new DataTable();
        try
        {
            dTable = p.Load();
        }
        catch (StackOverflowException ee)
        {
            string message = ee.Message.ToString();
        }
        finally
        {
            p = null;
        }
        return dTable;
    }
```

Comment: "not all codes returning a value." - if you catch an exception but don't re-throw then it'll fall out of the catch block to the end of the function without passing through a `return`. Also you can rewrite the try/finally using `using` blocks - that might be clearer - and you don't need to close and dispose the connection, dispose it enough (as I've been told off for before)

Comment: Can you provide a stack trace? You could also benefit from learning about the `using` statement.

Comment: I am new to multi layer which is this code.  How do I get stacktrace?  I usually did Label1.Text = ex.StackTrace.ToString().

Comment: I confused as to why you don't just create a new DataTable and return it?

Comment: http://codepad.org/yQZKlJWz   I think this is it(stacktrace)...and it's...long

Comment: Okay I am starting to get confused.  I think I need to take a step back.  Where can I relearn this as I am learning from samples...but this is way too confusing now.  Do I go c# asp.net or...sql tutorials...?

Comment: I tried to make a multilayer but I am confused...I don't know what goes where anymore.

Comment: It's weird that the sender in the stacktrace is `GridView` instead of `Page`. Do you have any events wired up in the front page for the `GridView`?

Answer (score 3):

First, I think the issue is probably in MasterCust. I think that however that is defined may be causing your issues. If you update your question on how this is defined, that may shed some additional light.

Second, you have a lot of extraneous code that could be confusing the issue. Here is what I think that you need to do to pare it down the bare minimum:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                BindGrid();
            }
        } 
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            // Note that this is for debug purposes only. Production code should log 
            // this exception somewhere so that it can be observed and dealt with
        }
    }

    private void BindGrid()
    {
        MasterCust.DataSource = BAL.Load();
        MasterCust.DataBind();
    }
```

Then your business access class:

```
public class BAL
{ 
    private static string connStr = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbCustConn"].ToString();
    private static string cmdStr = "Select * from MainDB";

    public static DataTable Load() // what is this for? (loads all the records from the database)
    {
        using (var adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdStr, connStr))
        {
            var ds = new DataSet();
            adp.Fill(ds);
            return ds.Tables[0];
        }
    }
}
```